# C# - CPU and memory issues when using smaller timer interval

Tags: c#, memory, timer, cpu

I have a timer in my application that fires every 10 ms. I know this is a very small value for a Windows timer and aware of the precision issues. Anyway, it causes the CPU usage to increase to 10% on average and the memory usage is slowly increasing but then eventually goes back down to a lower value. Without the timer, there are no CPU or memory issues. From what I've read, the memory increasing and then decreasing is a normal thing and it is due to Windows not releasing memory unless it has to. However, is this going to cause any performance problems with my application? Is 10% CPU usage going to cause problems as well? When I increase the timer to 100 ms it seems to be a little better but still seeing a similar type of effect. I need the timer interval to be as small as possible.

Comment: What kind of operations are you performing when the timer fires?

Comment: You really should clarify the problem... So far it looks like "Code uses CPU. I think it is a problem"...

Comment: It performs a database query (using the Entity framework) to check whether a new row was added to a table. (I didn't write it originally.)

Comment: Long time ago, I learned there is a way to have the sql server raise an event if a specified table was updated. I believe its far more efficient.

Comment: Why not just raise an event from the code which performs the database operation? Create an event that other code in the app may subscribe to and kill the timer altogether.

Comment: Instead of adding the "solved" section to your question, please put your solution down in an answers box. Answering your own questions is encouraged here, but questions and answers should be kept separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 10% CPU usage (in my opinion) is not a big deal. I mean it's ok but definitly not the best. It's ok if you will need to do a lot of extra stuff to achieve better performance.

I wrote a lot of apps that uses 20% CPU and it works kinda fine. However, a timer set to 10ms is kind of weird. I guess you want to use it to constantly check for something. If you are doing that, don't use timers at 10ms. It's better to use `event`s to do this. If you don't know events, here is a simple guide.

You declare an event like this:

```
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;
```

For the purpose of this example, I will put the event in a class called `MyClass`. When you want to raise the event i.e. make the event occur, do this:

```
SomethingHappened (this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Now let's see how do you subscribe to the event. Of course you need to create an object:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass ();
```

And then write a method to execute when the event happened. The return value type and parameters must be the same as this one:

```
public void DoSomething (object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

Now you do the subscription:

```
obj.SomethingHappened += DoSomething;
```

For more information, here's an MSDN tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I wonder how does this approach apply to sql server table, probably updated by different application from different computer.

Comment: I want to use events but we're about to release the software and I'm not going to be able to make an architectural change this late in the game (as much as I would like to). Having said that, I realized that my timer method is taking longer than 10ms on average which probably explains a lot about what's going on. Thought I saw much lower times before.

Comment: Actually, I think this is fine, because I disable and then reenable the timer again after the event is processed. So it should wait 10 ms in between each fired event.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. The issue was that I had some code in the timer event that was slowing everything down. After replacing a few lines of code the CPU usage went back down to 0% and memory is no longer increasing. Hopefully this may help someone else in the future.